# node.js and phantom.js in iOS?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, node.js, phantomjs

How can I get the items in the table written by this script in iOS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&cat=0-14&date=today+7-d&cmpt=q&content=1&cid=RISING_QUERIES_0_0&export=5&w=300&h=420"></script>
```

Any good tutorials maybe on `node.js` and `phantom.js` for iOS?

Comment: You should ask @AriyaHidayat. He's the developer of phantom.js. :)

Comment: It creates an iframe, and I don't think there is any way by which you can access cross domain iframe content