# Getting data from a document.write function

Tags: javascript, objective-c, document.write

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [node.js and phantom.js in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535629/node-js-and-phantom-js-in-ios)

How can I get data from this table in iOS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&cat=0-14&date=today+7-d&cmpt=q&content=1&cid=RISING_QUERIES_0_0&export=5&w=300&h=420"></script>
```

I think it's a document.write function, so I can't parse it. How can I get the data from the table then?

Any help is really strongly appreciated. Thx! Antoine

Comment: You just asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535629/node-js-and-phantom-js-in-ios

Comment: Do you want to get the actual trend? if yes why don't you use the google api's

Comment: There isn't one for google trends...

Comment: Downvote for asking the same question too frequently.

Comment: didn't get a helpful answer before, but fair enough

Comment: Why did you add objective c tag? Does this script run in a browser or in your own app? If it's your own app you might parse the response of the javascript source, get the src of the iframe and parse that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the document.write starts with:

```
<iframe width="300" height="420" src="//www.goo
```

You can't access anything in the iframe because of the browsers same origin policy.